# Why are exceptions inside else in try-except-else not re-thrown?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

I'm using `try`|`except`|`else`|`finally` in python.
If the code inside `else` throws an exception, I want my overall script to fail (after executing `finally`).
I'm finding that this is not happening. Exceptions inside `else` are being suppressed. Why?

## MWE

```
import requests
def foo():
    try:
        resp = requests.get("https://example.com")
        status = resp.status_code
        assert resp.status_code < 300, "Bad status code"
    except requests.exceptions.BaseHTTPError:
        status = None
    else:
        print("Starting else branch")

        # this should fail
        # because the body is not json
        print(f"Response body was {resp.json()}")

        print("Finishing else branch")
    finally:
        # save the result persistently,
        # regardless of if it was good or bad
        with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(status))
        return status

print(f"foo() gracefully returned {foo()}")
```

I've tried in python 3.6.9, 3.9.5 and 3.8.

## Desired behavior:

`resp.json()` throws a `simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError` exception inside `else`, which is then caught, `finally` is run, but then the exception from `else` is **re-thrown**, so the overall script fails with a `JSONDecodeError`.

`stdout` shows:

> starting else branch

and then an exception is thrown, with a traceback to `resp.json()`.

[The python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for the `else` in `try`|`except`|`else`|`finally` says:

> The use of the else clause is better than adding additional code to the try clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the try … except statement.

So it sounds like the purpose of the `else` clause is for putting code where you do *not* want exceptions to be caught. That's what I want. But it seems like exceptions in `else` *are* being caught.

(Note that in this example I want the AssertionError to result in the overall function failing, and the BaseHTTPError to be caught and handled gracefully. That doesn't really make sense for a real use case, but this is just a simple MWE.)

## Actual behavior

`stdout` says:

> Starting else branch
>
> foo() gracefully returned 200

The `JSONDecodeError` exception inside the `else` is caught, `finally` is executed, and the code returns `200`. That is, the exception in the `else` code was caught. So it seems the code in the `else` branch *was* protected by the `try`.

If I wanted `JSONDecodeError` to be caught for my `.json()` line, I would have just put it inside the `try`.
How do I make this script *not* catch the `JSONDecodeError` error?

Comment: From the docs `It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.` meaning, it's code that runs if there's no exception raised.

I think you should carefully read the docs, you are just not getting it right.

Comment: "code in the else branch *was* protected by the try"—No, was superseded by the return in the finally block

Comment: @Capie I definitely understood the conditions under which the `else` is run. The question is about what happens to exceptions thrown inside the `else`.  The issue was that I just wasn't aware of the nuance about the `return` statement in `finally`, which was addressed in a different paragraph of the docs to what you quoted.

Comment: The best way to handle errors that you do not want to catch is just not to catch them. That is why we specify what types of errors we want caught in the first place. If you are defining specific error types, this should be fairly easy to implement, no?

Comment: In my code I did not try to catch that `JSONDecodeError`, I specified only the `BaseHTTPError`, but `JSONDecodeError` gets caught anyway. That's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is perfectly documented:

> If `finally` is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The `try` clause is executed, including any `except` and `else` clauses. If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. The `finally` clause is executed. If there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the `finally` clause. If the `finally` clause raises another exception, the saved exception is set as the context of the new exception. If the `finally` clause executes a `return`, `break` or `continue` statement, the saved exception is discarded:
>
> ```
> >>> def f():
> ...     try:
> ...         1/0
> ...     finally:
> ...         return 42
> ...
> >>> f()
> 42
> ```
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try

To have exceptions inside `else` thrown after `finally` is executed, you must not have a `return` inside `finally`. Unindent it to move it outside the `finally` branch.

Comment: @false Thanks for the proposed addition, but modifying the value in `finally` makes little sense to me; that statement should simply be outside the `try` block, so it's a bad example and I wouldn't advocate for it.

Comment: Ok, how about I change the code inside `finally` in both the question and this answer, to make it more meaningful? (In my real code I do a database write to log the result, good or bad. I'll do something similar.)

Comment: I think we can leave this as is. It answers the question why it behaves this way. It doesn't necessarily need anything beyond that.

Comment: Whilst your answer was helpful, it took me a few re-reads to get it. In particular, your code snippet doesn't even contain an `else`, and there's nothing to explicitly say what change is required to the code to ensure exceptions in `else` are thrown for the overall script.
I've changed the question code now to justify a `finally`.

Comment: Well… you must not have a `return`, `break` or `continue` statement inside `finally`. If you do, any and all exceptions are discarded, nullified, void. That's exactly what it says. Generally code in the `finally` block shouldn't contain anything that has to do with the general flow of the code (like `return`, or altering values and such). Its job is to have a block of code that is guaranteed to always be executed, no matter if or how or where an exception is or isn't raised. — You *can* use it to override any exception, but you should do that very consciously and carefully.

Comment: (cont.) The typical use case for `finally` is to close files which have been opened or such things, something that must be guaranteed to run no matter what.